# .bashrc not read when shell script is invoked from desktop shortcut

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, shortcut-file

I have a simple problem understanding a behavior in linux. In short, on linux if i invoke my sh script from a 'Desktop Shortcut' then the script cannot see the latest environment variables (set in bashrc). So i was wondering that in what scope is this shell script located ?

To create a testcase and reproduce:

1. Create a simple shell script 'testme.sh' :

   ```
   !/bin/sh
   echo "Hi This is a test script checking the env var";
   echo "TESTVAR = $TESTVAR";
   read in
   echo "Done";
   ```
2. create a desktop shortcut for the script above.

   ```
    
   cd ~/Desktop
   vi mytest-desktop.desktop 


   //Contents for mytest-desktop.desktop are : 
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Name=TestAbhishek
   Exec=/home/abhishek/test/hello.sh
   Terminal=true
   ```
3. Now update your .bashrc file to set the variable

```
   export TESTVAR=test_this_variable
```

1. Open a brand new terminal and execute the script using it's complete path like '~/testme.sh'   //This can see the value for variable 'TESTVAR' from the .bashrc file.
2. Now, simply double click and execute the Desktop shortcut. 
   //This should open a terminal and print out value for 'TESTVAR' as blank. 
   //So my question is, who is the parent for the terminal opened by this shortcut?

I've tried this on RHL.
Im looking for a solution or a w/a for this problem, hope someone can help soon.

Thanks,
Abhishek.

Answer (score 11):

See the **INVOCATION** section of the bash manpage.  Here is an excerpt

> When bash is invoked as an interactive
>   login shell, or as a non-interactive
>   shell with the --login option, it
>   first reads and executes commands 
>   from  the file /etc/profile, if that
>   file exists.  After reading that file,
>   it looks for ~/.bash_profile,
>   ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that
>   order, and reads and executes commands
>   from the first one that exists and is
>   readable.  The --noprofile option may
>   be used when the shell is started to
>   inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, bash reads
>   and executes commands from the file
>   ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
>
> **When  an interactive shell that is not
>   a login shell is started, bash reads
>   and executes commands from ~/.bashrc,
>   if that file exists.** This may be
>   inhibited by using the --norc option. 
>   The --rcfile file option will force
>   bash to read and  execute  commands 
>   from  file instead of ~/.bashrc.

Long story short, if you want non-interactive shell's to have certain ENV vars set, then put them in `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`