# Using sed in a .sh file on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, scripting, sed, terminal

I am trying to parse some text files with the command line. part of this involves reattaching broken words in some badly-formatted emails. An example:

```
9,650 330,765.0  16.38% NYSE (000) 1,707,915 272,099.0  18.95%     Commodit=
ies Close Change % Change Crude Oil (Feb) 19.62 0.32  1.66% Heating Oil (Ja=
```

I want to grab 'Commodities.' I'm using this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n) to sed to get the job done.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7 and GNU sed version 4.2.1. If at the command line I enter

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/=\r\n//g' ./filename
```

sed works correctly. However if I run this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash


sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/=\r\n//g' filename
```

sed doesn't work. However, the same script works under Ubuntu's command line:

```
9,650 330,765.0  16.38% NYSE (000) 1,707,915 272,099.0  18.95%     Commodities Close Change % Change Crude Oil (Feb) 19.62 0.32  1.66% Heating Oil (Jan)
```

On my Mac, the simpler script

```
#!/bin/bash


sed 's/=//g' filename
```

successfully removes all the equal signs. I'm trying different combinations of characters to backslash out but without much success. Any hints to what the Mac terminal isn't liking?

Comment: The example file contains a single space after the last equal sign on each line. Could that be the reason your command is failing? Also, perhaps try changing your shebang to `#!/bin/sh` for it to work on OSX. Goodluck.

Comment: @steve thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately changing /bin/bash to /bin/sh didn't work. :( I updated the example file to remove the spaces, they are not in the actual file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a PATH setting. `/bin/bash`  uses the default `$PATH`; not sure why, but perhaps that depends on your normal working shell (is that bash), or in which dot-files your PATH settings are.

OS X comes with its own (BSD) sed, which is not the same as the GNU one, and thus doesn't work.
Running the `sed` command in the script will pick up the BSD sed, not your self-installed GNU sed. Use the full path to sed in the script, or set $PATH in your script before. Obviously, you don't have the problem on Ubuntu, since the default `sed` is GNU.

Comment: well, I put 'gsed' instead of 'sed' in my script and that seems to work. I must have it installed on MacPorts or something. You're right, the sed called by the script is different. Curiously, when i put `echo $PATH` in the script I was shown the same PATH I got from entering the same command on the command line.

Comment: If you can call `sed` form the command line but not from the script, and your `PATH` is the same, perhaps it's an alias that's not recognised/expanded in the script?

Comment: Thanks. I looked again, i have alias sed='gsed' in my .bashrc file. I tried moving it to my .bash_profile and .profile files as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477328/bashrc-not-read-when-shell-script-is-invoked-from-desktop-shortcut but my alias still isn't recognized in the script... Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Aliases are not expanded in non-interactive shells (such as your script). See e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases.