# Linux desktop file Exec doesn't used the user session

Tags: python, linux, freedesktop.org

I have a python script file that works perfectly when I use it from the terminal.

Now I have created the following `.desktop` file in order to launch it easily:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Test
GenericName=Test
Comment=My test script
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/test.py
Icon=/opt/test.png
Categories=Utils;
```

When I launch it the GTK window appear but clicking a button that call an init.d script make it working not properly.

Therefore adding `Terminal=true` make it working perfectly but I don't want to have that terminal open.

So I have then put the following code in order to log the environment variables:

```py
import os

with open("/tmp/py_env.log", "w") as env_log:
  env_log.write(str(os.environ))
```

and found differences.

So my question is how to write the .desktop file so that my application is running like if I start it from my terminal (without having an opened terminal :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks anyone to have participate to this question.

I have solved this issue by implemented use of `pkexec` instead of `gksudo`.
`pkexec` seems to reuse the current user environment then I don't have this issue anymore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is valid, but I think "replicating the terminal environment" is the wrong approach to solve it.

Indeed, what makes the application work is not the fact that it's *launched from the terminal*, it's that the terminal *happens to have* some environment variables which matter to your application.

Therefore, what you should aim for is to **have those environment variables set properly at all times**, rather than **assuming the terminal environment will always happen to contain them** all the time for all your users.

Thus, you should:

1. Check which environment variables are different between the two environments
2. Make a list of those which matter (i.e. those which would make the `.desktop` file work properly), and of what their value needs to be for the script to work
3. Either:

   - Create a wrapper script for your Python script, which initializes those environment variables properly, OR
   - Set those environment variables from inside the Python script itself.

Answer (score 0):

this question is similar to [.bashrc not read when shell script is invoked from desktop shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477328/bashrc-not-read-when-shell-script-is-invoked-from-desktop-shortcut)

- either initialize your environment in `~/.bash_profile` instead of
  `~/.bashrc`

OR

- make your `*.desktop` file call a wrapper that initializes your
  environment - e.g. by sourcing `~/.bashrc` (or whatever script is
  responsible now).

the second solution is more specific (does not effect all other unrelated launches of your shell) in should thus be preferred.

Comment: I understand the solution but it looks brittle to me because I'm using zsh so if other users use other terminals there will not be covered by this case. How can I handle all cases?