# how to make functions visible to bash scripts?

Tags: bash, function

I have a function called groovy defined in my .bashrc.

I have this bash script where I want to use groovy.

It says `./batch.sh: line 7: groovy: command not found`

Although I source .bashrc in the beginning of the script.

What am I missing ?

batch.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source ~/.bashrc
for file in *.html;
do
    name="${file%.html}"
    groovy "$name.html" "uncached/$name.mp3"
done;
```

part of .bashrc

```
function groovy {
    sed -n '/<pre>/,/<\/pre>/p' "$1" |  replace '<pre>' '' '</pre>' '' | hextomp3 - "$2"
}

function hextomp3 {
    echo "in $1"
    echo "out $2"
    echo "cut -c10-74 $1 | xxd -r -p - $2"
    cut -c10-74 "$1" | xxd -r -p - "$2"    
}
```

output :

```
chaouche@karabeela ~/DOWNLOADS/MUSIQUE $ ./batch.sh
./batch.sh: line 6: groovy: command not found
./batch.sh: line 6: groovy: command not found
./batch.sh: line 6: groovy: command not found
./batch.sh: line 6: groovy: command not found
./batch.sh: line 6: groovy: command not found
./batch.sh: line 6: groovy: command not found
```

Comment: What environment are you running it on? Have you tried using ~/.bash_profile instead [per this question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477328/bashrc-not-read-when-shell-script-is-invoked-from-desktop-shortcut) ?

Comment: Just a side note, but you might want to change your function name as it's confusing with [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Running) the dynamic language for the Java platform which can be run on the command line via the groovy command.

Comment: I was able to get this to run successfully on my box. Are you sure that you have the function in the right .bashrc? Note that you're using the ~ notation, so if you're sudo'ing, you might be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @Kasra I'm not sure to understand your question but I'll try a dumb answer : I'm using it locally on my machine as normal user.

Comment: @ychaouche It was a two sided question, my bad: 1. Are you running as sudo? 2. Is this OS X or a linux?

Comment: oh sorry yes linux as normal user.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` will refer to the `.bashrc` of the user that runs the script. Are you sure the correct `.bashrc` is being sourced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/bashrc`, `~/.bashrc` are **not** read when **not** running in an interactive mode.

You might see something similar to

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

or

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

in your `~/.bashrc`.

Consider adding your function to `~/.profile` or to `~/.bash_profile` (if the latter exists).

Comment: I believe you also need to export a shell function for it to be available in a child shell.

Comment: @chepner OP says that the file containing the function is being `source`d.

Comment: Ah, missed that. But why doesn't it work when `.bashrc` is explicitly sourced in `batch.sh`?

Comment: @chepner I must say that you didn't read the answer upon which you're commenting.  Sorry.

Comment: I read your answer and I don't have any clue what is interactive mode. I'm explicitly sourcing it in my script, would still interactive mode be relevant in my case ?

Comment: @ychaouche Issuing commands in your shell directly is interactive mode.  Issuing the same set of commands from within a script is **non-interactive**.

Comment: @devnull `batch.sh` is `sourced` *directly* in `batch.sh`, not manually at a shell prompt. `groovy` should be available in that shell.

Comment: @chepner Perhaps you didn't notice that `groovy` is defined in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: See my previous comment. This has absolutely *nothing* to do with which files are automatically sourced by the shell at start-up: the file is *explicitly* sourced by the script when it starts.

Comment: @chepner Yes, **but** that file that is *so explicitly sourced* contains something that forces it to `return` when non running interactively.

Comment: If that turns out to be the case, moving the function to `.profile`  (or some other automatically sourced file) will not help, because functions defined in the current environment are not available to scripts that run in child processes unless they are exported; hence my original comment.

Comment: @devnull may be right I have this in my source code : `if [[ $- != *i* ]] ; then
 # Shell is non-interactive.  Be done now!
 return
fi`

Comment: @devnull is it safe to remove that instruction ?

Comment: @ychaouche Don't remove that.  Instead move the `groovy` function to another file, say `~/.bashfunctions` and `source` that file instead.

Comment: If you really want it in your .bashrc for some reason, just add it before the `if [[ $- != *i* ]] ; then # Shell is non-interactive. Be done now! return fi` line.  I tried it an it works.