# Bash: Output all aliases and functions in a script

Tags: bash

Take the following script:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
set -f
result=$(compgen -A function)
echo $result
```

When running it outputs all my custom bash functions:

```
mp3gain pkg-pkgbuild-download quote quote_readline restart standby turnoff turnoff-timer youtubeConvert
```

However, when slightly changing the script to output aliases, the output is empty:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
set -f
result=$(compgen -A alias)
echo $result
```

Yet it is not empty if I run `compgen -A alias` directly.

My aliases are stored in `~/.bash_aliases` and my functions in `/.bash_functions`. Both are sources in `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Functions
if [ -f ~/.bash_functions ]; then
        . ~/.bash_functions
fi

# Aliases
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
        . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19279820/2235132) should explain the problem.

Comment: You are totally right. I forgot to mention that I am sourcing my aliases and functions. I edited my first post.

Comment: Source those files in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be willing to wager that the aliases are not sourced. This can be verified running this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
alias
```

If there is no output, the aliases are not sourced. Hence, that's why compgen returns an empty list when put in a script (non-sourced aliases) but works fine when run manually in a shell with sourced aliases.

Solution: put "source ~/.bash_aliases" near the top of your script to make sure they are invoked before running.